# how to delete a row in database using codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

hye, i'm trying to do 'delete function' for my modul. i've tried so many different ways for this. but it come out no result, some come with error.

this is my controller (named expert.php) :

```
public function remove() {
    $siri = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->Kepakaran_m->delete($siri);
    $this->view();
}
```

siri is the a field name (column name) in my table. it it primary key.

this is my model (named Kepakaran_m.php):

```
  function delete($siri) {
    $this->dbsmk->where('siri', $siri);
    $this->dbsmk->delete('kexpt003pakar');
    if ($this->dbsmk->affected_rows() == 1) {
        return TRUE;
    }  
    return FALSE;
  }
```

kexpt003pakar is the table name.

so my view is this (named kepakaran.php):

```
        <tbody>
          <?php if(empty($kepakaran)) { ?>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="8">Pengguna tidak mempunyai rekod kepakaran!</td>
            </tr>
          <?php } else {
            $num = 0;

            foreach ($kepakaran as $list_kepakaran) {
            $num++;
          ?>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $num; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $list_kepakaran->kategori; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $list_kepakaran->bidang; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $list_kepakaran->spesifik; ?></td>
              <!-- untuk keluarkan tahap -->
              <td><?php
                            if($list_kepakaran->tahap=='1'){
                                   echo "Sederhana"; 
                              }elseif ($list_kepakaran->tahap=='2') {
                  echo "Tinggi"; 
              }elseif ($list_kepakaran->tahap=='3') {
                  echo "Sangat Tinggi"; 
              }
                      ?>
              </td>
              <!-- done untuk keluarkan tahap -->

              <td><?php echo $list_kepakaran->biltahun; ?></td>
              <td>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tambahkepakaran"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button>
               <a href="<?php echo base_url('expert/remove/'); echo $list_kepakaran->siri; ?>" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Delete this record?')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          <?php }} ?>
          </tbody>
```

so the delete button is in this area >>siri; ?>" type="button".....

i hope your answer will help me to discover this up. thank you :)

Comment: did you try to print the value of `$siri` in `delete()` to make sure it has the desired value?

Comment: add this line after  
    $this->dbsmk->delete('kexpt003pakar');     echo $this->dbsmk->last_query(); exit; and check your executed query to figure out the problem

Comment: @Shihas i didn,t want to print the 'siri' value. btw i've got the answer. thank you :)

Comment: @Ryan thank you. i've tried this. and it hepls me. thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

What's the error? I think you just need to modify your codes becomes:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('expert/remove/'.$list_kepakaran->siri); ?>" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Delete this record?')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
```

Then it should be ok.

In order to use `uri` segment..do not forget to call `url` helper in `autoload.php`

Comment: the problem is the data holded ($siri) is not passed to database (i guess). i've tried the way u show me(thank you). it doesn't work for my code.

Comment: if my answer was correct then please mark as correct answer. Thanks

Comment: i use this answer for my code and it is done. this is the answer ==> $this->dbsmk->last_query(); exit;

Answer (score 0):

english is not my native language.

For solve your problem, you can check a lot of things.

- Did you forget to load model in your controller ?
- Try to dump value of `$siri` in your remove function and show response on your network tab in chrome devTools for example.
- If you don't call your controller, look at side of your href or open Application/config/routes.php for use routing and add this `$route['expert/remove/(:num)']['GET'] = "expert/remove/$1";`
- If `$siri` is empty look at the side of `$this->uri->segment(3);`
  Verify if you load correctly the helper.
  For that, go to `Application/config/autoload.php` and see if url is in helper `$autoload['helper'] = array('url','security','language', 'form', 'text');`